# How to convert Jquery code to React JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

How to convert jQuery code to ReactJS ?

```
$("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
});
```

Comment: You should see this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23585765/how-to-go-from-jquery-to-react-js

Comment: As mentioned, ReactJS don't use the same development logic. You should first learn components logic before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

React works in different way to manipulate your DOM and events. To achieve the same function, you can do something like this:

```
MyComponent extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      toggled: false
    };

    this.toggleMenu = this.toggleMenu.bind(this);
  }

  toggleMenu() {
    let isToggled = this.state.toggled;
    this.setState({ toggled: !isToggled});
  }

  render() {
    let buttonClass = (this.state.toggled) ? 'toggled' : '';
    return (
      <div className={buttonClass}>
         <button id="menu-toggle" onClick={this.toggleMenu}>Toggle Menu</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

Basically, different from jQuery, you should control your DOM with state and props. Please check React.js docs for conditional rendering: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Comment: I want to try this one https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-simple-sidebar/

Comment: 2 years later. Found this comment on Google because I am trying to do the same thing with one of their templates. Lolz. Their SB Admin 2 Template has a collapsible sidebar that I want to emulate with React and I am not skilled at all with Frontend Frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned before React is a different animal for certain reasons explained. To achieve the same functionality using React Hooks please refer to the following code :

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';

export default function MyComponent() {
  const[toggled,setToggled] = useState(false)
  const buttonClass = (toggled)? 'toggled':'';

  return(
    <div className={buttonClass}>
      <button 
        id="menu-toggled" 
        onClick={()=>setToggled(!toggled)}>
          press
        </button>
    </div>
  )
};
```

Please take a look at Stackblitz [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hooks-stackoverlfow-02?file=index.js)