# Passing only clicked element to onClick function - reactjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have multiple elements with same **className** and i want if some element (with className **history-node**) is clicked it should get className **active** along with current className.

But i am having an issue, there are childs of that element and if child elements gets clicked they also get class **Active**.

Here is the code:

```
<div className="history-node-container" key={index}>
  <div className="history-node" onClick={(e) => {this.handleHistoryClick(e.target)}}>
    <span className="history-title">{heading.action}</span>
    <span className="history-date">{moment(heading.added_at).format("MMMM Do, YYYY")}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**handleHistoryClick** function

```
handleHistoryClick(target){
  $('.history-node').removeClass('active'); //removing active class from all elements
  target.className = 'history-node active';
}
```

I want to run function when user click on element with className **history-node**

But if user clicks on **history-title**, ClickHandler gives class **active** to **history-title** element.

EXPECTED BEHAVIOUR: if history-node is clicked only history-node should get class **active**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One tip and how to solve your problem (In two ways)

**Tip**: Not usually the best idea to mix `React` with `jQuery`. React came in as a major paradigm shift in how we interact with the `DOM`. Try to read a little bit more about React, how it works, why is it so different from simply adding/removing elements in the `DOM` with jQ.

Some references to help you with that:

[How to go from jQuery to React.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23585765/how-to-go-from-jquery-to-react-js)

[Thinking in React for jQuery Programmers](https://www.codementor.io/binarymuse/react-components-from-a-jquery-programmer-background-du107k2lz)

---

Now, back to your question

You should use `currentTarget`.

As the `.history-title` and `.history-date` elements are wrapped within `.history-node`, any click on them will trigger it's parent's event, since `.history-node` body is `.history-title` + `.history-date`. That's the correct behavior. When you trigger an event in JS, the `event` object receives two parameters: `target`, which is the event triggering the event and `currentTarget`, the element that is actually listening for the event.

Now for the code:

**with JQ**

Component:

```
<div className="history-node-container" key={index}>
  <div className="history-node" onClick={handleHistoryClick}>
    <span className="history-title">{heading.action}</span>
    <span className="history-date">{moment(heading.added_at).format("MMMM Do, YYYY")}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Click:

```
handleHistoryClick(event){
  $('.history-node').removeClass('active')
  event.currentTarget.classList.add('active')
}
```

**The React way (Pure React, no modules)**

Component:

```
class HistoryNode extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { isActive: false }
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
    }

    handleClick(e) {
      let state = this.state
      this.setState({isActive: !state.isActive})
    }

    render() {
      return(
        <div className="history-node-container">
          <div className={`history-node ${this.state.isActive ? 'active' : ''}`} onClick={this.handleClick}>
            <span className="history-title">{heading.action}</span>
            <span className="history-date">
               {moment(heading.added_at).format("MMMM Do, YYYY")}</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    }
}
```

Notice how you don't need to manipulate the `DOM` at any moment at the React solution. You just attach your event to that particular component, define how it's state change should reflect on the UI and let React do the rest.

Hope it helps ;)

[Reference for `target` vs `currentTarget`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086427/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-currenttarget-property-and-target-property)

Comment: Great explanation though. Thanks a lot for your time and effort. 

I got it working.

Comment: Two comments:
* In the line `<div className={`history-node ${this.state.isActive ? 'active' : ''}`} onClick={handleHistoryClick}>`, it should be `onClick={this.handleClick}` (I submitted an edit)
* If you declare `handleClick` as `handleClick = () => {...` then you won't need `this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)` in the constructor

Answer (score 1):

I think the event propagates to child components.

Have you tried this ?

```
<div className="history-node-container" key={index}>
  <div className="history-node" onClick={handleHistoryClick}>
    <span className="history-title">{heading.action}</span>
    <span className="history-date">{moment(heading.added_at).format("MMMM Do, YYYY")}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

HandleClick function

```
handleHistoryClick(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  $('.history-node').removeClass('active');
  event.target.className = 'history-node active';
}
```

EDIT : You could make it simpler though (and without jQuery) using your component state. But without knowing how you wrote your component I cannot give you a snippet illustrating it. Be careful too as you interact directly with the DOM, this implies a performance loss. Using the React state allows you to avoid such thing!

Comment: Could you edit your original post with the entire component ?