# Should I use Reactjs for an ecommerce Website, or just stick to Jquery?

Tags: jquery, reactjs, e-commerce

I'm building an eCommerce site with Laravel backend. 
I can use ReactJs for the view but an SPA is not SEO friendly.

Will using ReactJs in a multipage setup (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41956465/how-to-create-multiple-page-app-using-react)) solve the SEO issue,
or should I just proceed with good ol' Jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using `react` over `jQuery`. You can use `react-router` to take care of routing and even do server side rendering using something like [next.js](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/). That will take care of SEO stuff.

`react` is much more powerful than `jQuery` in that it allows you use `state` and have logic within the component. Also since it does not do direct DOM manipulation it's much faster.

[This one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23594466/737124) explains it very. Worth the read.

Answer (score 0):

If the concern is SEO then you could control the User Friendly URL form Route and Custom Route Group. 
However, I heard (May be from jeffrey way) Laravel works better with Vue.js and You could always use Laravel Mix there. 
But all recommendation depends on your capability, usability and Project scope.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely recommend [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/)! It is a production-ready framework built on top of React.With Next.js You can create 100% SEO-friendly app with SPA-like routing.

jQuery is a library for querying DOM and definitely not considered the right tool for creating large apps nowadays.
With jQuery you would end up writing a ton of code, reinventing the wheel and with a codebase, no one would like to join present times.